# How Do You Validate a Query Containing Multiple Joins

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to validate that the data coming back from a multiple join query is correct.

This query is going to be run in a validated system and we need to prove that it is returning correct data.

I was told that we need to run queries so that each join is tested.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT 
  DISTINCT 
    tph.PROJECT, 
    p.T_PH_STUDY_TYPE, 
    p.PROTOCOL_TEMPLATE, 
    p.C_ISEPAGLP, 
    p.C_GLP_STUDYNAME, 
    tph.STUDY_SITE, 
    p.T_PH_MATERIAL_TYPE, 
    p.C_STUDY_YEAR, 
    p.T_PH_COMMENT, 
    tph.BATCH_REFERENCE, 
    tph.PRODUCT, 
    tph.ITEM_CODE,
    tph.PRODUCTION_DATE, 
    tph.BATCH_SIZE, 
    tph.C_VESSEL, 
    tph.C_VENDOR_BATCH, 
    tph.C_SUPPLIER, 
    tph.PACKAGING_TYPE, 
    tph.C_FILL_QTY, 
    tph.PACKAGING_DESCRIPTION,
    tph.C_EXPIRY_DATE, 
    tph.C_FILL_UNITS, 
    tph.C_PACKAGING_LINE, 
    tph.C_CONTAINER_PART_NO, 
    tph.C_CONTAINER_DESC, 
    tph.C_CLOSURE_PART_NO,
    tph.C_CLOSURE_DESC, 
    tph.C_SUBSTRATE_PART_NO, 
    tph.C_SUBSTRATE_DESC, 
    tph.C_FILM_SEAL_PART_NO, 
    tph.C_FILM_SEAL_DESC, 
    p.STATUS , 
    s.DATE_STARTED,
    t.ANALYSIS, 
    t.VERSION, 
    s.Sample_Number 
 FROM SAMPLE s 
 INNER JOIN Project p             ON s.PROJECT = p.NAME 
 INNER JOIN T_PH_TEST_ARTICLE tph ON tph.PROJECT = p.NAME 
 INNER JOIN TEST t                ON t.SAMPLE_NUMBER = s.SAMPLE_NUMBER 
 WHERE (###) ORDER BY 36, 34, 35 ASC
```

I was thinking about testing the query by choosing a parameter from each table, in combination with the other tables. In other words running a combination calculation.

What is the most efficient (easiest) way to test a query like this?

Comment: You run it on a test database where you know the answer.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, I am running queries to pull all the infor from the database and checking it against the above query. I'v been asked how to confirm that the joins are correct; that is our main concern.